# Function to check if there is a date in my database

Tags: r

Could you help me tweak this function below: basically it's a function that checks if the given date I choose is in my Test database. If not, it will show "This date is not in your `Test` database, otherwise it will show "This date is in your Test database".

```
#database

Test <- structure(
  list(dat= c("2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-03"),
       X= c(5,4,0)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
        

firstf <- function() {
if (The date is not in my database #I don't know how to write this here){
  print ("This date is not in your Test database)}
else {
print ("This date is in your Test database)
}
}

firstf("2021-01-01")
```

So, for example, I do `firstf("2021-01-01")`, is to look like "This date is in your test database". If I enter `firstf("2021-01-15")` it will show "This date is not in your test database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the date using `%in%`.

```
firstf <- function(database, date) {
  if (date %in% database$dat)
      print ("This date is in your Test database")
  else 
  print("This date is not in your Test database")
}

firstf(Test, "2021-01-01")
#[1] "This date is in your Test database"

firstf(Test, "2021-01-15")
#[1] "This date is not in your Test database"
```

Comment: Thanks ronak! There you insert `date %in% database$dat` , that meant checking if dates that are in my database, and if you are going to check dates that are not in my database what would it look like? I saw that you used `else`, but if had no `else`?

Comment: You can negate `%in%` by doing `!date %in% database$dat`